# what permissions I need to grant for user to use "Manage Content and Structure"

Tags: permissions

I granted Contribute permission to users. I modified the contribute permission and checked override checkout and approve items. even after this modification users aren't able to copy or move documents from one library to target library. "Inadequate permissions to "target library" to  complete this operation. Please suggest. Per Microsoft Contribute permissions is sufficient for this action. https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Work-with-site-content-and-structure-30fcaad9-02b1-4347-8b03-e1ccc5a4c19f

Comment: Added Approver and Hierarchy to the contribute permissions and now it's working. I really don't want user to modify the list settings (adding or removing columns, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

While the Contribute permission level is sufficient to access the "Manage Content and Structure" page, the specific permissions required for copying or moving documents between libraries are **Manage Permissions**, **Manage Web Site**, and **Add and Customize Pages**.